# Can someone tells me what's the logical error in this code?

Tags: java

**LOGICAL ERROR:** The output works fine and produces the 1st output, and when checked with the 2nd output, it produces the first statement `Kids: 6`, but the second statement `New baby, kids now: 7` is never produced and instead, `New baby, kids now: 4` is produced.

**HINT:** The hint given to me is that changes must be made in the specific lines of the code ONLY. You can see the code, it is mentioned there that the changes must be made in `callPersonInfo.java` only and that too in-between these lines `//changes must be made after this line. So NO changes above this line.` and `//changes must be made above this line. So NO changes below this line.` Rest of the code is fine.

**Expected 1st output:**

```
Kids: 3  
New baby, kids now: 4
```

**Expected 2nd output:** (NOT part of 1st output, but it should work with this as well just to check reliability of the code)

```
Kids: 6
New baby, kids now: 7
```

**Code:** (Runs fine, but logical error)

```
// ===== Code from file PersonInfo.java =====
public class PersonInfo {
   private int numKids;

   public void setNumKids(int personsKids) {
      numKids = personsKids;
      return;
   }

   public void incNumKids() {
      numKids = numKids + 1;
      return;
   }

   public int getNumKids() {
      return numKids;
   }
}
// ===== end =====

// ===== Code from file CallPersonInfo.java =====
public class CallPersonInfo {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      PersonInfo person1 = new PersonInfo();

      person1.setNumKids(3);


//changes must be made after this line. So NO changes above this line.

      System.out.println("Kids: " + person1.getNumKids());

      person1.setNumKids(4);
      System.out.println("New baby, kids now: " + person1.getNumKids());

//changes must be made above this line. So NO changes below this line.     

      return;
   }
}
// ===== end =====
```

Comment: This is a very elementary question. Can you tell us what the problem you've having solving it ? Are you having a problem understanding the question? What _should_ the code be doing, at a general level?

Comment: Expected output 2 is not produced, but 1 is produced and that's fine.

Comment: Are you changing `person1.setNumKids(3)` to `person1.setNumKids(6)`? Because I can't see how you're even getting "Kids: 6" as an output.

Comment: @BrianD, yup! I have spent so long on this, but still stuck!

Comment: @GhostRider - Can you say in words - what should the code be doing?

Comment: @splrs, actually I'm doing this activity on Zybooks. It's like a web platform where we type and fix the code and the compiler online will test this code. So it will test it with 6 as well after 3.

Comment: ie. What should it do if there are initiallly 0 kids, or initially 101 kids?

Comment: @dwjohnston, it should work according to that.

Comment: According to what?

Comment: @dwjohnston, I'm weak in this JAVA so I also don't know, but I'm expecting that result in the question. Expected output 2 Please help.

Comment: What would you expect if were initially 101 kids, or 0 kids?

Comment: @dwjohnston, if 0 kids then `Kids: 0  
New baby, kids now: 1` and if kids 101 then output `Kids: 101  
New baby, kids now: 102`

Comment: @GhostRider - now we're getting somewhere. What does the existing code do? This line  -> `person1.setNumKids(4);`  - What should it do instead?

Comment: @dwjohnston, `Kids: 4 
New baby kids now: 5`

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the value of `numKids` each time and not incrementing (adding to) it as you want to.

Call `incNumKids()` instead of `setNumKids(4)` and you'll add 1 to the number pass in on the first call of `setNumKids()`.

Note: What's not made clear in question is that that `person1.setNumKids(3)` isn't actually a static piece of code, and that you're apparently also editing this to get the initial "Kids: X" output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm bound to make changes in the specific area of the code ONLY. That area is specified in the  `CallPersonInfo.java` by `//changes must be made after this line. So NO changes above this line.` and this line `//changes must be made above this line. So NO changes below this line.` **In simple words, NO changes outside this area have to be made** . this is what I received in question and code. So, there needs to be made changes in this area only and it will solve the problem. Can you help? Much appreciated!